# Retrieving duplicate from two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have two tables.

table A:

```
code desc
001   sam
002   bob
003   mala
004   anna
```

table B:

```
code  desc
001  marley
001  sam
002  bob
003 mala
004 anna
005 sana
```

I want to retrieve all the rows from both tables where the `code` value is common, regardless of the value of `desc`. That is, my final result should be:

```
001 marley
001 sam 
002 bob 
003 mala
004 anna
```

I try this but it's not returning me the duplicate that is `001 marley`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM TABLEA
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLEB);
```

Comment: You need to explain the logic for deriving your result set.  Why `001 Marley` but not `005 Sana`.  In other words, what is your definition of "duplicate"?

Comment: Actually i want to retrieve common code from both table. in table A i have 001, table 2 i have 2 record of 001. i want to have all 001 from both table along with desc. even if the desc is different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I suspect you just want a MySQL option, here is the Oracle RDBMS solution.  It uses a couple of neat features: the INTERSECT operator to produce a set of common values, and the WITH clause to improve the performance of the sub-query.  It also employs the UNION operator which to produces a set of all the distinct values.

```
with cc as ( select code from a
             intersect 
             select code from b )
select * from a
where code in ( select code from cc )
union 
select * from b
where code in ( select code from cc )
/
```

[Here is Teh Obliquitory Fiddle!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aaf41/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
SELECT a.code, a.desc
  FROM tablea a JOIN tableb b
    ON a.code = b.code
UNION 
SELECT b.code, b.desc
  FROM tablea a JOIN tableb b
    ON a.code = b.code
 ORDER BY code, `desc`
```

Output:

```
| CODE |   DESC |
|------|--------|
|    1 | marley |
|    1 |    sam |
|    2 |    bob |
|    3 |   mala |
|    4 |   anna |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b019/4)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question, because marley is only in table 2, so it's not a duplicate.
But you can get your desired result set if you use

```
select code, desc from tableB
where code in (select code from tableA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query. It will solve your problem & it is the most efficient solution too.

```
SELECT tableB.*
FROM
tableB
INNER JOIN
tableA
ON ( tableB.code = tableA.code );
```

Comment: Although this will work for the posted data set I don't believe it meets the OP's requirements (although I concede they are still a bit vague).  Your query wouldn't return `001 sam` if it were only in table A whereas I think the OP would still want both values of `desc` in the result set.

Comment: I think he wants only those codes that are in both the tables. So if `001` was present in only 1 table, then it should not be in the output.

Comment: If A only has `001 sam` and B only has `001 marley` (i.e. one row per table) then I think the OP's requirements  still expect two hits (`sam,marley`) whereas your query would return one (`marley`).  But I say again. it's not obvious because the posted data doesn't cover all possibilities.

Comment: yes.. my query would return only 1 row, in that case.. Don't know what OP wants..

Comment: Thanks guys. 001 is repeated twice in table B. and i want it to output both even if the desc is different.

Answer (score 0):

Peterm's solution works, but it does unnecessary work in creating and then removing duplicates.  A more efficient solution that works in both databases is:

```
select a.code, a."desc"
from tablea a
where exists (select 1 from tableb b where a.code = b.code)
union all
select b.code, b."desc"
from tableb b
where exists (select 1 from tablea b where a.code = b.code);
```

These queries will be more efficient with an index on `tablea(code)`, `tableb(code)`.  You can also add `desc` to each index as well.

Because `desc` is a keyword in SQL, I have put it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the most efficient SQL giving expected output:

```
SELECT B.code, B.des
FROM B INNER JOIN A
ON ( B.code = A.code );
```

Most of SQL published here are right and doing the job but Manu's SQL is also efficient and gives the weird O/P as well (*Tested in Oracle 11G*).

I am not sure why he conceded in comments that '*..my query would return only 1 row.*'

Since the join is by 'code', it will match 2 rows with 001. Now, pull'desc' from B and you get the job done.